# dynamically assign functions from list

Tags: r

Context:

I'm trying to set up some mock data testing and I have saved some mock data down as csvs in a directory called 'test/'.

Each file relates to a get_data type function e.g. the mock data for get_energy() is stored as test/get_energy.csv.

I'd like to use list.files() to assign functions to my environment that read the csv.

```
files<-list.files('test/')

for (name in substr(files,1,nchar(files)-4)){
  assign(name,function(){read.csv(eval(parse(text=paste0('test/',name,'.csv')))) })
}
```

but when I try and see the source code for the function get_energy by running

```
get_energy
```

it returns

```
function(){read.csv(eval(parse(text=paste0('test/',name,'.csv'))))}
```

whereas I need it to evaluate the string expression so that it returns

```
function(){read.csv('test/get_energy.csv')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the whole function definition in the string like so:

```
files <- list.files("test/", pattern = 'csv$')

for (name in substr(files,1,nchar(files)-4)) {
  assign(name, eval(parse(text = paste0('function(){ read.csv(', '"test/', name, '.csv', '")}'))))
}
```